# How to capture annotations on generic super class type arguments?

Tags: java, generics, annotations

With java 8 it's possible to create an annotation with the target ElementType.TYPE_USE.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

This annotation can be applied on types passed to a generic super class, for example:

```
public class ClassA extends BaseClass<@MyAnnotation ClassB,@MyAnnotation ClassC>{
...
}
```

With the following code, I can easily retrieved dynamically from an instance of ClassA the list of type parameters of the super class BaseClass.

```
ClassA instanceOfA = new ClassA();
...
Class classOfA = instanceOfA.getClass();
ParameterizedType type =  (ParameterizedType)classOfA.getGenericSuperclass();
Type[] types = type.getActualTypeArguments();

// types[0] --> ClassB
// types[1] --> ClassC
```

From there, I tried to find a way to retrieve the annotation for each type argument but without success.

Is there a way to retrieve these annotations dynamically (runtime)? Thanks

**Edit:**
Additional precision, I would like to support the following use case:

```
public class ClassA extends BaseClass<@Annotation1 ClassB,@Annotation2 ClassC>{
...
}

public class ClassD extends BaseClass<@Annotation3 ClassB,@Annotation4 ClassC>{
...
}
```

In this example, ClassB is annotated differently in the context of ClassA or ClassD (same thing for ClassC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky:

```
 import java.lang.reflect.*;

 AnnotatedType baseClassAt = classOfA.getAnnotatedSuperclass();
 assert (at instanceof AnnotatedParameterizedType);

 AnnotatedType[] aTypes = ((AnnotatedParameterizedType)baseClassAt)
     .getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments();
 assert aTypes.length == 2;

 MyAnnotation myAnno0 = aTypes[0].getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
 MyAnnotation myAnno1 = aTypes[1].getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
```

Comment: Thanks wero, works like a charm. I missed the getAnnotatedSuperclass!

Answer (score 0):

For annotations at class level we can use `getAnnotations()` method for each class object. In your code we need to type cast the `Type` to `Class` and get annotations for it.

For example:

```
Class classOfA = instanceOfA.getClass();
ParameterizedType type =  (ParameterizedType)classOfA.getGenericSuperclass();
Type[] types = type.getActualTypeArguments();

for(Type t: types){
    System.out.println(t.getTypeName());

    Annotation[] ans = ((Class) t).getAnnotations();
    for(Annotation an: ans){
        System.out.println(an.annotationType());
    }
}
```

Following is a complete example with two different annotations to highlight the difference:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class AnnotationChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA instanceOfA = new ClassA();

        Class classOfA = instanceOfA.getClass();
        ParameterizedType type =  (ParameterizedType)classOfA.getGenericSuperclass();
        Type[] types = type.getActualTypeArguments();

        for(Type t: types){
            System.out.println(t.getTypeName());

            Annotation[] ans = ((Class) t).getAnnotations();
            for(Annotation an: ans){
                System.out.println(an.annotationType());
            }
        }

    }

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface MyAnnotation1 {

}


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface MyAnnotation2 {

}


class ClassA extends BaseClass<ClassB,ClassC>{

}

class BaseClass<ClassB, ClassC> {

}

@MyAnnotation1
class ClassB {

}

@MyAnnotation2
class ClassC {

}
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't respond to the question. The question was to find annotations defined on type arguments and not defined on class. For example I would like to support the following declaration: class ClassA1 extends BaseClass<@MyAnnotation1 ClassB,@MyAnnotation2 ClassC> and class ClassA2 extends BaseClass<@MyAnnotation2 ClassB,@MyAnnotation1 ClassC>. See my edit in the question for more precisions.